# Not getting expected min_resources_ when using scikit-learn's HalvingGridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I am trying to tune model hyperparameters using scikit-learn's HalvingGridSearchCV class and the iterations it uses do not appear correct to me. I am using the default `min_resources="exhaust"`, as I want the last iteration to use the entire training set, or as much as possible. In my case when I test over 8 hyperparameters with a halving factor of 2 I get one of either two problems.

The first is that in some cases it runs the last iteration for only one candidate hyperparameter set. Something [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#amount-of-resource-and-number-of-candidates-at-each-iteration) states that it shouldn't do:

> the process stops at the first iteration which evaluates factor=2 candidates: the best candidate is the best out of these 2 candidates. It is not necessary to run an additional iteration

Over 1000 generated samples, running a halving search with a factor of two over a grid of 8 possible hyperparameter combinations I would expect this to be done in 3 iterations of `n_candidates_=[8, 4, 2]` with `n_resources_=[250, 500, 1000]`. What I get however is `n_candidates_=[8, 4, 2, 1]` with `n_resources_=[125, 250, 500, 1000]` where the first iteration is done with a lower than expected min_resources and the last one is unnecessary.

Another problem happens when I run the same search over 100 generated samples, instead of my expected 3 iterations of `n_candidates_=[8, 4, 2]` with `n_resources_=[25, 50, 100]`, I get `n_candidates_=[8, 4, 2]` with `n_resources_=[20, 40, 80]`. Here the number of iterations seems the correct but the initial `n_resources_` is too low and doesn't reach 100 in the last iteration as it should with `min_resources="exhaust"`.

These issues appear to be data dependent, I first noticed the iterations were not what I expected when trying to run a small test on a subset of the Fashion-MNIST dataset. In that case, running the same hyperparameter search over 200 samples gives `n_candidates_=[8, 4]` with `n_resources_=[100, 200]`, on generated samples I get `n_candidates_=[8, 4, 2, 1]` with `n_resources_=[25, 50, 100, 200]`. Neither of which are the expected `n_candidates_=[8, 4, 2]` with `n_resources_=[50, 100, 200]`.

When I use a halving factor of 3 or 4 I get the results I expect, I've only seen the issue with 2.

I am not sure if I am misunderstanding the expected behavior of successive halving or if I am using it wrong in some way. Or if it is just a bug in scikit-learn, I am using version 1.4.0 of the library.

The following code snippet will result in `n_candidates_=[8, 4, 2, 1]` and `n_resources_=[125, 250, 500, 1000]` instead of the `n_candidates_=[8, 4, 2]` and `n_resources_=[250, 500, 1000]` I expect. It can also be changed to obtain the other cases I highlighted by changing num_samples or un-commenting the Fashion-MNIST code and commenting out the make_classification() line.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml, make_classification
from sklearn.experimental import enable_halving_search_cv 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, HalvingGridSearchCV
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
num_samples = 1000  # or 100, or 200

# If testing on Fashion-MNIST, this will download the dataset
# data_fash = fetch_openml(name="Fashion-MNIST")
# X_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(
#                              data_fash.data, data_fash.target, train_size=num_samples, random_state=rng
#                              )

X_train, y_train = make_classification(n_samples=num_samples, n_features=20, random_state=rng)

print("Train samples: ", len(X_train))

param_grid = {"criterion": ["gini", "entropy"],
              "min_samples_split": [2, 3, 4, 5]}

cls = DecisionTreeClassifier()

grid = HalvingGridSearchCV(
           cls, param_grid, factor=2, min_resources="exhaust", scoring="accuracy", cv=5
           )

grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(grid.n_candidates_)
print(grid.n_resources_)
```

Comment: Given that `HalvingGridSearch` is still experimental, this is very likely an implementation bug. In fact, I believe I have identified the issue to be in how resources and candidates are calculated in the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9e38cd00d032f777312e639477f1f52f3ea4b3b7/sklearn/model_selection/_search_successive_halving.py#L310-L360) - but I will need to spend some time verifying if my ideas are correct...

Comment: I think it's more likely to be [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9e38cd00d032f777312e639477f1f52f3ea4b3b7/sklearn/model_selection/_search_successive_halving.py#L272).

Comment: See also https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/27422